# `mean` not producing right answer

Tags: r, mean

As above, anyone knows what is happening?

```
m1 <- 0.457842055395572
m2 <- 0.587127416942505
sum(m1, m2)/2
mean(m1, m2)
```

Output:

```
> m1 <- 0.457842055395572
> m2 <- 0.587127416942505
> sum(m1, m2)/2
[1] 0.5224847
> mean(m1, m2)
[1] 0.4578421
```

Restarted R and still the same. Am on R 3.0 x86 Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mean` is an S3 function that takes a single main argument which is a single R object (most commonly a vector) of quantities, and any other arguments get passed on to other methods through `...`. In this they get passed onto `mean.default` which has two extra named arguments, `trim` and `na.rm`. Therefore your second value will be interpreted as the trim amount (though you can't trim a single value).

What you want to type is:

```
mean(c(m1, m2))
[1] 0.5224847
```

Comment: `mean.default` actually has three named arguments, meaning that here m2 was silently interpreted as `trim`; now _that's_ dangerously mean.

Comment: @baptiste Good point, thanks. I've updated the answer to take this into account.